# Updating a field to the primary keys value after a model is created in Django 2.1

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model named Project that has recursive foreign keys to itself.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_root_parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='root_parent',null=True)
    project_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'parent',null=True)
```

This is the desired functionality I want:

- If the project does not have a parent project the field is set to the
  created objects primary key.
- If the project doesn't have a root parent project the field is set to 
  the created objects primary key.

Ideally i want the default value of the field to be set to the primary key.
If this is not possible then I need to be able to update the value after the primary key is generated and the model is instantiated in Django.

I have looked at overriding the save method or using the `post_save` signal but I am unsure that either of these methods are correct.

Comment: Every recursion should have an end, yours wouldn't have one. What is the larger idea behind this?

Comment: @KlausD. This structure will allow me to have an unlimited amount of sub-projects in a project.

Comment: Your desired functionality will give you the opposite: unlimited ancestor projects.

Comment: @KlausD. It works in SQL. I tested it manually. It should work in Django. There are other conditions i need to enforce, but I need to get this working first so I can at least create an initial project.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_root_parent = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='root_parent',null=True, blank=True)
    project_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'parent',null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.project_root_parent is None:
            self.project_root_parent = self
        if self.project_parent is None:
            self.project_parent = self
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The trick is to make sure `blank=True` when creating the `CharFields` because its different than setting them to nullable.

Call the super constructor to save the fields as blank.
Once the project instance exists then change the fields to itself.
Then call the super constructor again to detect changes and save the model.